# Finding the shortest item in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How would you go about finding the shortest item stored in an array?? This is what I have so far but I am lost at what to do next. I have tried a few type of loops with no luck. I feel like there is a simpler way of doing this.

Here is what I am suppose to do, I am not looking for you to do my homework, just to guide me.

For this Homework, you will be writing an application which determines which of all the strings the user enters is the shortest.   The application will start with the welcome message followed by instructions to use the “.” character when they are finished entering strings.   The application is to continue to prompt the user to enter strings as long as “.” is not entered. Every time a string is entered, the application will store it in an ArrayList object.  When the user is done entering strings, the ArrayList object will be passed to a method named printShortestString.  This method will determine which of all the strings the user entered is the shortest and print that string along with its length. Finally the application exists with the good-bye message.

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShortestString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("WELCOME TO SHORTEST STRING\n\n");
    System.out.printf("Type \".\" when done entering data.\n\n");

    ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean keepAsking = true;
    while (keepAsking) {
        System.out.printf("Enter string: ");
        String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (userInput.equals(".")) {
            keepAsking = false;
        } else {
            myArray.add(userInput);
        }
    }

    printShortestString(myArray);

    System.out.printf("\n\nGOODBYE!\n");

    keyboard.close();
}

public static void printShortestString(ArrayList<String> myArray) {
    int count;
    int index = 0;
    boolean endLoop = false;
    while (endLoop = !true) {
        for (count = 0; count < myArray.get(index).length(); count++) {
            if (count == myArray.get(index).length()) {
                System.out.printf("\nShortest string is %s with length %d",
                        myArray.get(index).toString(), myArray.get(index)
                                .length());
                endLoop = true;
            } else

                index++;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort the array using `Arrays.sort()` method passing an appropriate `Comparator`?

Comment: @RohitJain: I seriously doubt that is the desired answer for a simple homework assignment.

Comment: There are several issues here:  1) you have too many loops.  2) your for loop should be looping over the length of myArray, not the length of the index.  Simply make one loop that goes over each item in the array.  Hang on to minimum length seen in the list, and what it's index is.  After the loop exits, print the string at the index you saved.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to do it very simply I would iterrate over the array, keeping the shortest answer found in a variable... Quite like this :

```
if (!arrayWithAllValues.isEmpty()) {
    String shortestValue = arrayWithAllValues.get(0);
    for ( String current : arrayWithAllValues ) {
        if ( current.length() < shortestValue.length() ) {
            shortestValue = current;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the best way nor the fastest way, but it is the simplest way in my opinion.

Comment: Setting ```shortestValue``` to ```null``` will give you a ```NullPointerException``` at ```shortestValue.length()```.

Answer (score 0):

A simple (but not the most efficient) way is to sort the array by length, and just output the first item which is then the shortest;

```java
public static void printShortestString(ArrayList<String> myArray) {

    if(myArray.size() == 0)
        return;                  // No output on empty array

    Collections.sort(myArray, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.length() - s2.length();
        }
    });

    System.out.printf("\nShortest string is %s with length %d", 
      myArray.get(0), myArray.get(0).length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. It's VERY easy to follow. Simply print the returned String. Also, *in the context used*, a null will never be passed.

```
private static String getShortestString(ArrayList<String> stringArrayList)
{
    int shortestIndex = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (String currentString : stringArrayList)
    {
        if (currentString.length() < stringArrayList.get(shortestIndex).length())
        {
            shortestIndex = index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return stringArrayList.get(shortestIndex);
}
```